# Multiple users updating Excel from app

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have created a form in Visual Studio 2013 which is used to enter data in Excel by multiple users at same time. It works perfectly fine except if two users open form at the same time or if one has clicked submit and the form is still processing. Then it shows the following error for the other person.

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. 
>          Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Any help on how I can rectify this?

```
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    Dim xlapp As New excel.Application
    Dim workbook As excel.Workbook
    Dim worksheet As excel.Worksheet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("2.xlsx")
        xlapp.Visible = False
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If workbook.MultiUserEditing Then
            workbook.AcceptAllChanges()
            workbook.Save()
        End If

        Dim row As Long
        Dim alpha As Long = 0
        row = 5
        With worksheet
            Do While .Cells(row, 4).value IsNot Nothing
                row = row + 1
            Loop

            .Cells(row, 2).value = Me.fname.Text
            .Cells(row, 3).value = Me.lname.Text
            Me.fullname.Text = Me.fname.Text + Me.lname.Text
            .Cells(row, 4).value = Me.fullname.Text
        End With
        xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
        workbook.SaveAs("2.xlsx", AccessMode:=excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @JohnKoerner I have edited my question and added the error

Comment: Where is this Excel workbook saved? Is it some sort of shared drive? How is the connection to the shared drive? I have a very similar issue with shared workbooks on shared drive (operated directly, not through vb.net though).

Comment: @Eleshar ya the workbook is saved in a shared drive. The people who'll be using this form and excel file will be given the link to the drive

Comment: My personal suspicion is this happens due to occasional shaky connection - when the workbook is saved, it seems to be simply closed for any sort of editing by anyone else. For me, it prevents other people from saving during the time so I suspect your problem will be similar. Not sure if this is possible to resolve within your script.

Comment: Add a try catch block and write the exception to a log file (you should probably continue to re-throw it and crash your application).  Once you determine what kind of exception it is, you can handle it specifically and then determine how your application should behave in that scenario.

Comment: hi @JohnKoerner sorry I didn't understand. I am new to all this so please help me with the code.

Comment: Sharing an Excel file with multiple users who are all inputting information is a very bad idea, as you can tell.  If this Excel file is on a shared drive, you will probably see all kinds of corruption very soon.  If the Excel file is hosted in a SharePoint site, you can probably get away with this setup for a short while.  Again, though, this is a very bad idea, overall.  You should probably use Access to collect information from multiple users.  You can easily create a FE and BE setup.  Or, create a simple ASP.NET web-based form, and use that to collect the info.  Use SQL Server on the BE.

Comment: @JohnKoerner I added try-catch block around my code. But, now it shows "the file is locked. Try again later" or, "The file is opened by another user.Do you want to open it as read only" I don't want my users to see all this. It should just act as a normal form to enter data without showing these popup boxes. How do I rectify this?

Comment: @ryguy7272 They just want to use Excel and Visuall Studio. Nothing else.